# How to know if a person has seizures?

Tags: brain, nerves, seizure

Could you please let us know if the following are symptoms of seizures in a 16-year-old:

1. He goes sudden unconsciousness while speaking normally
2. There were no convulsions.
3. When it happens he start moving to a corner without his conscious and then falls on floor with bending mouth and fingers unconsciously.
4. No response even we put room keys or iron rod in hands (it takes 10 minutes to become conscious even if we put these things in hand)
5. After it happened and he became conscious, we took him to the nearest hospital and blood pressure is normal.

He has had an MRI scan and EEG (when conscious) and the results are normal. Do we need to take these tests during unconsciousness to get accurate results?

Please help us understanding his condition. We contacted doctors here but they are not sure that it is seizures, as the test results are normal.

He has shown this type of behaviour a few times in the last 1 and a half years.

We will meet a nearby doctor but your suggestions will help us to understand about his condition.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone on the internet to answer this question.

Comment: I'm curious if you've got a diagnosis on this from a doctor by now. If not, read https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1860900/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are we to say?
This is a very delicate issue, and misjudgements from us could lead to severe consequences.

Let's assume that the person does in fact suffer from seizures and the SE-Community convinces you of this.
Assuming you are from a country with regulations on medicine, there will be nothing you can do, apart from checking Dr. Google to understand what seizure exactly is, how it works and what possible cures are. Be asserted though that Dr. Google May not provide you with the best answer.
=> You will have to go to the hospital and get him/her checked. The answers couldn't help you in any way.

Let's assume that the person does in fact suffer from seizures but the SE-Community wrongly tells you he/she doesn't.
If this would prevent you from visiting the hospital, it would put a serious burden on the suffering person. As you stated in the question, you would, as I hope, visit the hospital no matter of the outcome.
=> You will have to go to the hospital and get him/her checked. The answers couldn't help you in any way.

**Concluding, the next thing to do is go and visit a hospital.**

As the OP asked whether the symptoms are  likely linked to seizure:

> When it happens he start moving to a corner without his conscious and then falls on floor with bending mouth and fingers unconsciously.

To me, this looks more like a psychological issue than a seizure...
I assume that the person can't remember anything about this, as you mention that he/she is unconscious. 
Does he/she notice they black out?

Comment: I asked this question just to get an information because no doctor is able to detect the problem as the test results are normal. Are we missing something. If the test results are normal, then why he is behaving like that. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any diseases that can be detected only when they occurred and not when he is normal.

Comment: He underwent medical tests after 24 hours of that happened but all the test results are normal